# What authority does the Benelux parliament have?

Tags: parliament, europe, netherlands, belgium, luxembourg

Today I discovered there is such a thing as a [Benelux Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benelux_Parliament).

However, neither the Wikipedia page nor the [official website](https://www.beneluxparl.eu/) (Dutch and French only) give a whole lot of information on what it actually *does*; it only seems to describe various procedures and such.

- What authority does it have? What sort of legislation can it pass?
- How does it relate to the national parliaments and the EU parliament?

Comment: Dutch Wikipedia says: None.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name "parliament" is something of a misnomer here. A parliament is commonly understood to be some sort of legislative body with the power to make laws.

However, the Benelux parliament does none of that, and is little more than a series of meetings between representatives of the three countries to discuss various matters that concern all three countries. It can publish reports and *advice* the national parliaments, who are free to completely ignore it. In other words, it is one of many advisory organisations that exist..

Note that while it's commonly called the "Benelux parliament" (including on its own website), the actual name is "Benelux inter-parliamentary assembly", which is a much more appropriate and less confusing name.

Source for the above (both Dutch, sorry):

- [Missie Beneluxraad](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerleden/commissies/bene/missie_beneluxraad)
- [Delegatie naar de Raadgevende Interparlementaire Beneluxraad](https://www.eerstekamer.nl/commissies/benelux)

Comment: A better translation would be "Benelux Council" but perhaps that name didn't ring as nicely to the reporters.